# What happens when I unsubscribe from an Observable chain?

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava in an Android app I'm using. I want to know what happens when I unsubscribe from an `Observable` chain.

Assume I'm referring to the following observable chain:

```
sourceObservable
    .map { ... }
    .doOnNext { ... }
    .flatMap { ... }
```

I see 3 possible answers:

1. When I unsubscribe, the source observable is stopped i.e the sourceObservable stops emitting items. The last emitted item goes down the chain till it's end. It causes each operator to fire.
2. When I unsubscribe, the source observable stops. The last emitted item doesn't go down but the operator it is currently going through(say `doOnNext`) is allowed to finish.
3. When I unsubscribe, the source observable stops and no more code is executed at all. It means that say I was using `doOnNext`, the code in `doOnNext` will stop where it is and will not be allowed to finish.

Which one(if any) of them is correct? Does the answer depend on whether the source observable is hot or cold? On the operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if an item is emitted and you imediatly dispose the stream the item want stop it will be processed till it finish processing but no more items will be emitted.

so if you watch this example maybe you will understands better

```
     observable = Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(aLong -> {
                System.out.println("1");
                return aLong;
            })
            .map(aLong -> {
                observable.dispose();
                System.out.println("2");
                return aLong;
            })
             .map(aLong -> {
                 observable.dispose();
                 System.out.println("3");
                 return aLong;
             })
             .doOnNext(aLong -> System.out.println("4"))
             .map(aLong -> {
                 observable.dispose();
                 System.out.println("5");
                 return aLong;
             })
            .subscribe();
}
```

In this stream only the first item will be processed till the end of stream so even if the first job that we do is unsubscribe we will still process emitted item so we unsubscribe from the source of emmiting

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But according to this discussion, flatMap behaves differently: [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6228#issue-365095749). I'm confused.

Comment: @NightMare yes in case of flatmap you insert another stream so if you have disposed before flatmap the stream in flatmap wont be subscribed so the stream will stop before flatmap

Comment: @NightMare if you are not clear the flatmap is another stream that is subscribed in every emit.

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)